# Active if null then hide div in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I think I'm going to have to use Jquery for this.

I have a print button that I only want to show if my array has data in it.

Here's my really simplified version of what I'm trying to accomplish

HTML

```
<?include 'anotherpage.php'?>
<button class='printButton' name='printButton'>Print</button>
```

PHP

```
$data = array();
if($statement == true){
 array_push($data, 'some value', 'another value');
}
if (empty($data)){
  echo "No trace currently found";
  **<<I want to set a hidden class to the button here somehow>>**
}
```

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. I'm still trying to grasp the whole JQuery thing.

Comment: what effort have you made to add it to your button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just include the button IF there is $statement == true?

Another way could be to set an jQuery / JavaScript function that hides the button.
Then if there should be no button, print a html part which calls the function.

Something like this:

jQuery

```
hidePrintButton = function() 
{
    $('.printbutton').hide();
}
```

PHP

```
if (empty($data)){
  echo "No trace currently found";
  echo '<script>';
  echo 'hidePrintButton();';
  echo '</script>';
}
```

Comment: This was the best answer out of all of them due to the multiple pages and not being able to move the button in my if statement. Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

What about just putting the button inside the if statement in PHP?

**PHP**

```
$data = array();
if($statement == true){
 array_push($data, 'some value', 'another value');
 echo "<button class='printButton' name='printButton'>Print</button>";
}
if (empty($data)){
  echo "No trace currently found";
  **<<I want to set a hidden class to the button here somehow>>**
}
```

**HTML**

```
<?include 'anotherpage.php'?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the button is allready rendered on the page, and assuming there is only one button with class printButton, using jquery you could do something like this:

if (empty($data)){
      echo "No trace currently found";
      echo "$('.printButton').hide();"; 
   }

But this is not a good way to do it because you are mixing server behaviour and client behaviour, which will result in code difficult to maintain and debug.
You better rewrite your code to use only php, not printing the button in the first place if it is not needed, or using a class to hide it if it could be needed later.
Using a class to hide the button:

```
$hideClass = "";
if (empty($data)){
    $hideClass = "hideButton";    
}
echo "<button class='printButton $hideClass' name='printButton'>Print</button>";
```

This way, if you later need to show the button with jquery, you could call:

```
$('.printButton').removeClass('hideButton');
```